# Characteristic Polynomial Calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant, gaussian-elimination

I have a problem in my homework in which I have to find the characteristic polynomial of the following matrix:

[image: Matrix A]

**I know the final solution is:**

[image: final solution]

However, my answer keeps getting wrong whenever I calculate with the following way:
I know that I have to find the determinant of: (λI-A), but I decided to use some Gauss methods to simplify the matrix, so I won't get a x^3 in my final polynomial.

Therefore, I did the following actions:
[image: The way I tried to solve the problem]

Please help me get what I did wrong, and this would be a great help for me.

Thank you,

Alan

Comment: Elementary operations do not preserve eigenvalues/characteristic polynomial/etc.

Comment: It you do elementary transformations on $A$ you must do the same on the matrix $\lambda I$.

Comment: @Bernard so everything I do I must do within the final determinent? Thank you.

Comment: Yes but row or column operations are not very interesting here, because of $\lambda$, except occasionally for sign change. Sarrus's rule will be more useful.

Comment: @Bernard If I found the characteristic polymonial X^3-3X^2+3x-1, how do I find eigenvalues? I have a X^3 here.

Comment: It's a remarkable identity: $(x-1)^3$.